# Complex matrix manipulation

Tags: r, image, matrix

My data look like this, X and Y are the center of a defect. I want to assign the defect in a matrix.

```
defect_ID X Y X_range Y_range
1         2 3  5        0
2         7 12 1        2
```

I created a matrix 200*200 with only 0s. I want to put 1 in the matrix in the following way:

Every coordinate X Y will be 1. For example, we can see *ID 1* which will allow  1 to my cell of coordinate (2,3). *ID 2* will allow 1 to my cell (7,12).

I have done this with the code

```
img<-matrix(0,200,200)
img[cbind(data[,X],data[,Y])]<-1
```

Now I want to do something tricky.
I take a defect_ID and I want to assign the value 1 to all points around this defect using my X_range and Y_range value. For 1 defect, we take the center (X,Y) and we move using X and Y_range.

pseudo code

```
for defect_ID 1
img[X,Y]<-1
img[X+ 1:X_range,Y]<-1
img[X,Y+1:Y_range]<-1
```

For example, if we look at ID 1, I want to assign 1 to point (2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,3),(6,3),(7,3)

In case i have X_range and Y_range>1. X Y will be the center. Then I want to move in only one direction at the time.
For example for ID 2 i want to assign 1 to my cells (7,12),(8,12),(7,13),(7,14)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "move"?!

Comment: I mean modify adjacent cells using X_range and Y_range values; for defect 1, center is (2,3), X_range=c(1,2,3,4,5). So i want to find cell (2+1,3),(2+2,3)... and assign them value 1. May be "move" isn't the appropriate word.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = matrix(0,20,15)
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  sx = data$X[i]:(data$X[i]+data$Y_range[i])
  sy = data$Y[i]:(data$Y[i]+data$X_range[i])

  img[sx,sy] = 1
}
```

This should work for the first part at least. I'm not too clear on the second one. What if the range is odd? which direction should i choose?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
data <- tibble(defect_ID=c(1,2),X=c(2,7),Y=c(3,12),X_range=c(5,1),Y_range=c(0,2))
```

Input data:

```
> data
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  defect_ID     X     Y X_range Y_range
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1         1     2     3       5       0
2         2     7    12       1       2
```

Create matrix:

```
data_mat <- matrix(0,200,200)
```

Assign ones:

```
for (i in 1:2) { # Change this to the length of your dataset
  data_mat[data[[i,'X']]:data[[i,'X']]+data[[i,'X_range']],data[[i,'Y']]] <- 1
  data_mat[data[[i,'X']],data[[i,'Y']]:data[[i,'Y']]+data[[i,'Y_range']]] <- 1
}
```

Output:

```
> data_mat[1:10,1:14]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
 [7,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
```